# List remote branches by commiter & modification data

Tags: git

I can use

```
git ls-remote
```

to list the branches on my remote repository ([documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html)). If there are lots and lots of them how do I know which ones would be useful to fetch? The kind of commands I imagine proving useful for such a task would be

1. Log all the commits on the remote repository in reverse date-time
   order showing which branches they were on; or
2. List all the branches on a remote repository containing changes to a 
   specific file

I cannot find either of these commands. What command line tools are available in git to help work out which of the branches listed by `git ls-remote` might be usefully fetched?

Comment: The word "useful(ly)" in this question is highly subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you which branches you wish to fetch, you have to know your project and which branch what does in contains,

If you want to use it the way you asked i can supply with with scripts to print out the content you asked for.

### Print list of branches with the last modification date + last commiter

```
# update local repository to get all the remote branches & tags    
git fetch --all --prune

# list all the branches from the remote and process them one at a time
for ref in $(git branch -r ); 
do 
    # print the last log message of the given branch
    git log -n1 $ref 
    
    # print out (in colors) the the data, using log format varaibles
    --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%an%Creset %C(yellow)%d%Creset %C(bold blue)%cr%Creset%n" ;
     
    # end of loop, print + sort by commiter & date 
    done | cat | sort -n -k1,1
```